# class_replaceMethod in Objective-c is not working on a Swift class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have an issue when a swift class is inspected by some Objective-c code, I can get the original method for the class but whenever I set the item it results in the method being removed from the class.

I am assuming that my IMP does not meet the specifications required of a swift class, but I have not found much in the way of help online.

My simple example is as follows:

```
+(void)injectPropertyTrapsFor:(NSString*)propName reader:(IMP)r writer:(IMP)w typeEncoding:(const char*)type {

    IMP oldMethod = class_replaceMethod([self class], NSSelectorFromString(propName), r, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s@:", type] UTF8String]);
    IMP replacedMethod = class_getClassMethod([self class], NSSelectorFromString(propName));

}
```

oldMethod is not nil and contains (in my case) the swift class' getter for a property.  But once I have replaced it, the subsequent call to get the method again returns nil.

I have looped through the methods using the code below, and it returns pretty normal looking propertyName and setPropertyName: methods as I would expect.

```
int unsigned numMethods;
Method *methods = class_copyMethodList([self class], &numMethods);
for (int i = 0; i < numMethods; i++) {
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromSelector(method_getName(methods[i])));
}
free(methods);
```

The output of which produces the following:

```
initWithPrimaryKeyValue:
forename
setForename:
surname
setSurname:
favoriteColour
setFavoriteColour:
.cxx_destruct
init
```

When I print description on the existing methods they look like the following.

```
Printing description of oldMethod:
(IMP) oldMethod = 0x000000010d72f440 (DBAccess Test`@objc DBAccess_Test.ViewController.Person.surname.getter : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<ObjectiveC.NSString> at ViewController.swift)
```

I'm not sure what I wish to achieve is even possible, but it would be nice to find some kind of solution.

TLDR Version:  How do I intercept the get/set of properties from Objective-c in a swift class that I have no knowledge of or code access too?

Edit:

For reference this is the swift class:

```
class Person: DBObject  {

    var forename:NSString!
    var surname:NSString!
    var age:Int!
    var favoriteColour:NSString!
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Assuming your code works on Objective C classes, adding the dynamic keyword should fix the exchange: `dynamic var forename:...`

Comment: Thanks @BrianNickel, unfortunately the same problem exists.  the replacement does not work.  I can confirm that this code does work fine with an obj-c class, but not with a swift one (it inherits from a Obj-c class).

Comment: Okay, looking into this, I have zero evidence, but this feels like i'm playing around with class method implementations, but the properties are instance methods and it just always "happened" to work before in obj-c.  More by dumb luck, than decent coding.

Answer (score 1):

After this long time, I do not know whether know you do fix this problem.
Because I meet this problem recently, and I fix it in the end.
So I want share something here.

```
static let methodExchange : () = {

    var sysSEL = #selector(sendAction(_:to:for:))
    var systemMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(WHCButton.self, sysSEL)
    var mySEL = #selector(WHCSendAction(_:to:for:))
    var myMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(WHCButton.self, mySEL)
    var didAddMethod = class_addMethod(WHCButton.self, sysSEL, method_getImplementation(myMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(myMethod))
    if didAddMethod == true
    {
        class_replaceMethod(WHCButton.self, mySEL, method_getImplementation(systemMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(systemMethod))
    }
    else
    {
        method_exchangeImplementations(systemMethod, myMethod)
    }
}()

dynamic func WHCSendAction(_ action: Selector, to target: Any?, for event: UIEvent?)
{
    if (NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 - self.WHCEventTime) < self.WHCEventInterval
    {
        return
    }
    if self.WHCEventInterval > 0
    {
        self.WHCEventTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
    }
    self.WHCSendAction(action, to: target, for: event)
}

private override init(frame: CGRect)
{
    super.init(frame: frame)
    _ = WHCButton.methodExchange
}
```

It works now.
1. the most important is add "dynamic" to the func you want to exchange.
2. "+load" and "+initialize" can not be inherited now. And "dispatch_once" cannot be used now. Instead of these methods, I offer the new alternative.

Hope this can help you a little bit.